# Extracting the text from error object (via response) and manipulate or show it in vue template

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to show the errors of the form, I am doing it with an array and I show them with a for each the problem is that it shows me the error but with brackets and quotes.

**mutations.js**

```
createUser(state) {
    var url = urlUser
    axios.post(url, {
        id: state.idUser,
        name: state.newUser.name,
        email: state.newUser.email,
        password: state.newUser.password,
        //cant_client: state.newUser.cant_client,
        cant_vehicle: state.newUser.cant_vehicle
        //url: window.location.host + "/acceso/" + md5(state.newUser.password)
    }).then(response => {
        state.newUser = {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            url: ''
        }
        state.errorsLaravel = []
        toastr.success('Usuario generado con éxito')
    }).catch(error => {
        <!-- here -->
        state.errorsLaravel = error.response.data
        <!-- here -->
    })
},
```

**index.vue**

```
<form action="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="createUser">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
             <label for="name">Nombre</label>
             <input v-validate="'required|min:4|max:190'"
                    :class="{'input': true, 'is-invalid': errors.has('name') }"
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    class="form-control" v-model="newUser.name">
           
              <div v-for="(error, index) in errorsLaravel" class="text-danger" :key="index">
                   <p>{{ error.name }}</p>
              </div>
       
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 mt-2">
             <label></label>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i> Guardar</button>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

[image]

show me this way, please your help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<div v-for="(error, key) in errorsLaravel" class="text-danger" :key="key">
    <p>{{key}} : {{ error }} : {{ error[0] }}</p>
</div>
```

This will give you the `keys` of the errors and `error` itself that is attached to the key. Also, if you have array of `errors` that is attached to the specific key you can iterate it as well like I gave an example of index 0 `error[0]`.

**In case of inside loop to work with array of erros**

```
<div v-for="(error, key) in errorsLaravel" class="text-danger" :key="key">
    <p v-for="(errorItem, index) in error" :key="index">{{ errorItem }}</p>
    
</div>
```

Moreover, if you want to put some conditions on the basis of `keys` , you can use `key` inside the loop and make your logics.

**In case of selective errors that are linked to specific key**

```
<div v-for="(error, key) in errorsLaravel" class="text-danger" :key="key">
    <div v-if="key === 'name'">
    <p v-for="(errorItem, index) in error" :key="index">{{ errorItem }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bracket and quotes inside the error means that there can be more than one `error` that are specified to certain `key`. That's why errors are in array that are linked to specific key. One `key` can hold more than one `errors`

Answer (score 1):

How about you change your template to print

`{{ error.name[0] }}`
Alternatively you could change what you're pushing into `state.errorsLaravel`. It's hard to tell without seeing the data but perhaps you could push `error.response.data[0]` and keep the above to simply `error.name`

Comment: it doesn't work, it doesn't show me anything @RuNpiXelruN