# get the values of a specific key from Django queryset json data and pass them to vueJS

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I have used Django2 to develop a web app, frontend using vue.
In the view function, I have rendered some json data to frontend.
But in the frontend, I am not sure how to pass all the value of a specific key in the Json data  to a JavaScript dictionary value.
I have tried to use += to add the data, but failed to get the data in my case. No data was shown in the table. Only the first row could work

View.py:

```
def Browse_and_adopt(request):
query_results_book = Title.objects.all()
query_results_book_json = serializers.serialize('json', query_results_book)
return render(request, 'main.html', {"query_results_book_json": query_results_book_json})
```

main.html:


{{ row.title }}
{{ row.author }}

```
    <script>
          var query_results_book = {{ query_results_book_json|safe}};

    var book_row = {title: query_results_book[0].fields.title, author: query_results_book[0].fields.author };

    for (var i=1; i < query_results_book.length; i += 1){
        book_row += {title: query_results_book[i].fields.title, author: ''};
    }


    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data:() => ({
            filter: '',
            rows: [book_row]
        }),
</script>
```

sample json:

```
{author: "Bill Gates", title: "test"}
```

How could I pass all the data in this json data in vueJS?

Comment: Please add your sample json data with question so I can tell you exactly what's problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning a List of Titles in `query_results_book_json` and then trying to access it as if it was only 1 item in :

```
var book = {title: query_results_book_json.title, author: query_results_book_json.author};
```

You will have to iterate over that result in order to get the book you want, or change the query to just return the book you need.

EDIT:

You could add something like this:

```
<script>
    var query_results_book = {{ query_results_book_json|safe}};
    var book = query_results_book[0];
</script>
```

EDIT 2 (now that you added examples):

In order to access those dict keys you have to use the [''] notation.

So for example to get the first book's title in javascript you would so something like this:

```
query_results_book[0]['title']
```

You can try this by logging a for loop like this:

```
<script>
for (let i = 0; i < query_results_book.length; i++) {  
   console.log(query_results_book[i]['title'])
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you are doing something like that you should look into adding a filter to your view and filtering it from Django and not the front end.

Comment: I want to make one Title in one row, so could only filter in frontend

Comment: for (var i=0; i < query_results_book.length; i += 1){

}

Comment: Try this:
for (let i = 0; i < query_results_book.length; i++) { 
  console.log(query_results_book_json[i]['title'])
}

Comment: tried ur method, but get some error in for loop: vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"

Comment: So you have something wrong in your result.
What do you see when you do : console.log(query_results_book) ?

Comment: console.log(query_results_book) returns a json, that's correct, but seems like only one json item could be passed to  vue, if I book_row += XXX in for loop and passed more book_row contains more than one item to vue, error coours.
''};

Comment: you should update your question saying that you are using vue.

Answer (score 0):

As you have JSON object Try this.

```
<div v-for="(item, key) in jsonData" :key="key">
    <p>{{key}} : {{ item }}</p>
</div>
```

This will give you the `keys` of the jsonData and `item` itself that is attached to the `key`.

Moreover, if you want to put some conditions on the basis of `keys` , you can use `key` inside the loop and make your logics.

**In case of selective items that are linked to specific key**

```
<div v-for="(item, key) in jsonData" :key="key">
    <div v-if="key === 'title'">
    <p>{{ item }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want a little bit more exposure on similar thing with vuejs, have a look at this also,
[Extracting the text from error object (via response) and manipulate or show it in vue template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68203548/extracting-the-text-from-error-object-via-response-and-manipulate-or-show-it-i/68205126#68205126)
it will help you to understand the manipulation of json data via vuejs.

Comment: Sorry, I tried ur method but not working. I have to make a table for all the data in json. so have to use rows: [book_row] in vue data